# Desktop linux is totally unstable (processes crash)

Tags: linux, crash

This is an Ubuntu desktop with various testing tools running. 14.04, x64.

Some rare process crashes started around 2 weeks ago and now a lot of different applications crash from time to time with Segmentation fault. Sometimes there are up to 7 crashes per hour and it's really annoying. I've no idea what's going on.

Some dmesg examples:

`[17813.482175] traps: chrome[29693] general protection ip:7fedd2653632 sp:7fffd3a9ec40 error:0 in chrome[7fedd08b5000+51d2000]
[17849.376004] traps: phantomjs[29901] general protection ip:f28f22 sp:7fffb03928d0 error:0 in phantomjs[400000+228e000]`

I suspect the reason lays in some system libraries because the applications that crash are completely different - from Python and Java to GUI things like Chrome.

It might be because of some filesystem error. **How can I check all the system files for corruption?** Probably comparing them with their original checksum. Yes I know there are some checksums in every package but don't ask me to check all these checksums manually for thousands of system files.

And if it doesn't help... **How can I then determine the actual reason of these crashes?**

Thanks!

Comment: It seems it's because of the RAM hardware errors. Memtest found a lot of errors, probably on all of the 4 memory chips. Kingston, what happened? =(

Answer (score 1):

Hardware RAM chips issues =(

Nuff said.

Comment: I've already had similar issues, and it was a faulty RAM chip. Test the memory using Memtest86 or Memtest86+. Read also: http://www.bitwizard.nl/sig11/

Comment: Its good to answer your own question. But please include the steps taken in your answer. Otherwise future readers have to go allover the comments, to find out what happened and how the solution was found ;-)

Btw you are lucky that the machine still boots. On my first try using linux, my system did not boot and randomly crashed, because my ram was corrupted in the very place the kernel was loaded.